# How to revert changes to a build configuration in TeamCity

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have done a number of changes to a build configuration in TeamCity 8. I know I can see an audit trail of the changes that I have done to the build configuration and I can check the details of each individual change, but I wonder if I can select one of those previous versions of the build configuration and restore it; there doesn't seem to be any obvious option in TeamCity for this.

For the avoidance of doubt, I'm not after reverting changes in the source code, but in the build configuration of TeamCity. I changed a few parameters, build steps, triggers, etc., and I want to revert those changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of TeamCity 2017, there is a link to a page with recent changes to a configuration:

[image]

Press 'view history' and you will end up on a page where there's a list of changes.

Press 'view change':

[image]

There you will see a "diff" comparison, identical to the one you have in git:

[image]

Sometimes it's hard to navigate, but you can surely see what was changed. This is especially useful for accidents when you deleted a piece of script, and saved the configuration. This can get your script back.

Hope it helps you after you after 8 years and 4 months!

Comment: It does! Changing this to the right answer now. Thanks.

Comment: lmao after 8 years xD

Comment: I’m very patient 

Answer (score 12):

You are right ,there is no obvious option in Teamcity to rollback to a previous version.

However, all teamcity build configurations are maintained in a xml file on the local disk drive in the Local Build Server. The files are created in a rolling format (the latest config is called config.xml, the one previous to it is config-1..xml). If you can figure out from the audit page on which exact xml you want to rollback to, you can copy the backed up config.xml to the recent one, or you can make the changes manually.

I would recommend playing with this on a test target first and then doing it on the original target.